# Family of analytic functions from unit disk to the plane minus a line

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, conformal-geometry, normal-families

*Let $\mathcal F$ be the family of analytic functions on the unit disk $\,\mathbb D=\{z: \lvert z\rvert<1 \},$ such that 
$f[\mathbb D] \subset \mathbb C\!\smallsetminus\!(-\infty, 0]$. Show that $\mathcal F$ is a normal family.*

(Normal Family= relatively compact= *every* sequence contains a subsequence which converges uniformly on *every* compact subset of $\mathbb D$)

EDIT. I see that this is immediate from Montel's theorem, but can it be proved somewhat easily without that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Note that $\mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]$ is a simply connected domain, and hence there exists a conformal map
$$\varphi : \mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]\to\mathbb D.$$ Next observe that the family 
$$
\mathcal G=\{\varphi\circ f : f\in\mathcal F\}
$$
is bounded and hence a normal family. Next, if $\{\varphi\circ f_n\}$ converges on compact subsets of $\mathbb D$, then so does the sequence
$$
f_n=\varphi^{-1}\circ(\varphi\circ f_n), \quad n\in\mathbb N.
$$

Comment: wonderful. thanks.